# set a dynamic iframe src with loader link options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i want to make we webpage that contain an iframe witch will have a dynamic Src. So The Scr will be fixed from the beginning in the webpage link. So when someone will visit the webpage (where it is the iframe), will click on this Link:

```
Link: http://"somedomain.com/
```

But what i want, is to modify the iframe Src in that page by this link. So The Link it will be like that.

```
Link: http://"somedomain.com/?s=specified_source_of_the_iframe
```

So Like that, that iframe will take that specified source by the variable "s".
"s" could be a link or just a variable name.

What i was thinking about, is to make this solution.

```
<body onload="Setiframe();">
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src=""></iframe>
<script>
function Setiframe(){
document.getElementById('iframe').setAttribute("src",s);
//or if "s" was a variable, it will be a link. or other method. it's not a problem for me. the problem's to access to the link data
}
```

I know that this's working with PHP, but i don't have any clue about PHP. and i don't want to use it because my webpage is almost done.

Please any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can access to the search atribute, of the location object it contains the querystring, then process it to get wath u want, for your test string specifically (http://"somedomain.com/?s=specified_source_of_the_iframe), this works:

```
function setIframe() {//I used a diferent function name ! check it! :)
   var s = location.search;
   s = s.replace('?s=', '');
   document.getElementById('iframe').setAttribute("src", s);
}
```

Comment: Think you it do what i want! So the tip's to use location.search i will make some searches to learn more about it. Think you again